# NAudio on Windows "N" versions

Tags: .net, naudio

I have Windows 8 KN (N versions are without Media Player and its components).

This doesn't have any ACM decoders installed, so I installed LAME MP3 ACM. (both 32 and 64 bit)

I checked it though NAudio demo app, and it is there.

But if I try to play an MP3 (even trough the demo app) it crashes with "AcmNotPossible calling AcmStreamOpen".

Is it possible to play audio with NAudio without installing the media pack for these versions of windows?
Does NAudio rely on the ACM codec only or some of these windows components?

EDIT: After installing Windows6.2-KB2703761-x64 (Media Feature Pack for N and KN versions of Windows 8) NAudio works.

So my question is: "Is there a way to play an MP3 with NAudio and .NET that does not require this to be installed?".

[image: screenshots]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use any ACM codec, the WAVEFORMATEX you pass in must match exactly what the codec wants. It's likely that the LAME MP3 codec uses different structures to the Fraunhofer one that comes with Windows. You can examine the input and output waveformat structures using the NAudioDemo application, looking on the ACM page.

MP3FileReader allows a pluggable MP3 frame decompressor, so if the DirectX Media Object MP3 decoder is you can set up MP3FileReader to use it with the constructor that takes a func to build an IMp3FrameDecompressor. If that doesn't work, you can implement your own IMp3FrameDecompressor function, that uses whatever codec you like, or even a fully managed one (e.g. using [NLayer](http://nlayer.codeplex.com)). Ultimately that's probably your best option if you don't want to be reliant at all on what codecs are installed on the machine.

Comment: Hi Mark, my problem is not making the waveformat work with LAME codec. If I install the Media Feature Pack, it will work. But that is what I want to avoid. Installing optional windows updates is not passable in our opinion. Both ACM and DMO dont work as frame decompressors without the media pack. As for NLayer: I tried as some files fail deep down in Nlayer when playing them (reading past end of stream), and since I don't know how to fix that bugs I decided to avoid it.